# UBUS systems calll getting hanged while restarting

Tags: objective-c, operating-system, filesystems, prototype, objective-c++

I added ubus code in my development environment for communication between two processes. The ubus system calls (`ubus_send_event` or `ubus_add_object`) are blocking while rebooting and restarting the device. This causes the system to hang. How can I fix this?

Comment: It is not standard question

Comment: Please consult this page to improve your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask